# ConLanging w/ Raspberry Pi?

Tags: conlang-creation, tools

Is there any coding/program that can be used in raspberry pi for creating a language? Like the ability to create a dictionary with sounds? Or an interactive creative process to start making words and meanings?

Comment: As the Raspberry Pi supports both Linux and Windows, probably most of the programs listed in the other question could be run on it.